# Different labels on JSON file importing to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I have a JSON file that I want to input into the database.

One has timestamp, data and title. But the other one consist of timestamp, attachments, data and title. It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1609189389,
    "data": [
      {
        "post": "Do the people who live here are in this Facebook group?"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Iwa posted in Student International Grup."
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1600768874,
    "attachments": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "media": {
              "uri": "photos_and_videos/your_posts/120080212_10224394.jpg",
              "creation_timestamp": 1600768848,
              "media_metadata": {
                "photo_metadata": {
                  "exif_data": [
                    {
                      "upload_ip": "91.102.240.87"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "title": "",
              "description": "Does someone have this book that is not used anymore? Thanks!"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "data": [
      {
        "post": "Does someone have thisbook that is not used anymore? Thanks!"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Iwa posted in Marketplace."
  }
]
```

I already create a database table like this:

```
 Schema::create('my_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->longText('attachments')->nullable();
            $table->longText('data');
            $table->string('timestamp');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And I tried to parse the JSON file like this:

```
 $json = File::get("database/your_posts_1.json");
        $data = json_decode($json);
        foreach($data as $obj) {
                My_post::create(array(
                    'attachments' => json_encode($obj->attachments),
                    'timestamp' => $obj->timestamp,
                    'data' => json_encode($obj->data),
                    'title' => $obj->title
                ));
            }
```

But it gave me ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$attachments. When I remove the first part of the JSON file it works, but with two different labels, it gave me that error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Your first part doesn't have `attachments`, check first if `attachments` is/are available, then add them

Comment: I realized that. I'm really new to programming, can you give me an example of how to check it?

Comment: `if(isset($obj->attachments)) { ... }`

Comment: This fix my problems! Thanks!